# Are the adjectives always placed behind nouns?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, noms

I am a ground beginner. So, sorry for any misunderstanding.

I have come across the sentence:  "Elle a une robe rouge"

So, is it always that adjectives are placed behind nouns, or are there special cases where this is done and somewhere this isn't done?

PS: I would really appreciate if the answer is in English. As I am a beginner, I might not get with a french answer properly.

Comment: @Kareen Thank You.  That question should help :)